# Cant understand why my approach isnt right when iam adding a condition with "and" to look some names in the database

Tags: sql

so i get some data from IMDB for Movies and i wanted to find the movies that both Jonny Depp and Helena Bonham Carter starred in them
i tried this code

```
SELECT title
FROM movies
JOIN stars ON stars.movie_id = movies.id
JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
**WHERE name = "Johnny Depp" AND name  = "Helena Bonham Carter")**
```

the last part seems to not work this way and i have to write it like this

```
SELECT title
FROM movies
JOIN stars ON stars.movie_id = movies.id
JOIN people ON people.id = stars.person_id
WHERE name = "Johnny Depp" AND movie_id IN 
(SELECT movie_id FROM people JOIN stars on stars.person_id = people.id WHERE name  = "Helena Bonham Carter")
```

Why using the first aproach i dont get the results?

Comment: Please define "seems to not work". :-D

Comment: `where name... and name...` refers to the *same* row - a name cannot be two different values any more than 1 = 2 so this predicate is always false.

Comment: Aaaah, @stu is right of course!

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be Johnny and Helena at the same time. You could use your `IN` approach or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT title
FROM movies m
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM stars s
    WHERE s.movie_id = m.movie_id 
    AND s.name = "Johnny Depp"
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM stars s
    WHERE s.movie_id = m.movie_id 
    AND s.name  = "Helena Bonham Carter"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The column *name* cannot be two different values at the same time, which is what your predicate is testing.

Instead something like the following (untested) should work, we filter on the name being in the set of two names and count to make sure only movies with two unique names are returned:

```
select m.title
from movies m
join stars s on s.movie_id = m.id
join people p on p.id = s.person_id
where p.name in('Johnny Depp', 'Helena Bonham Carter')
group by m.title
having Count(distinct p.name) = 2;
```

Comment: i understand nad your solution is right but for some reason with m,p,s shortcuts it doesnt play

Comment: I'm sorry that doesn't make any sense and I don't know what *with m,p,s shortcuts* means, there's nothing here that's not ansi sql.

Comment: i mean you write from movies m whats that m means?

Comment: Ah - sorry - m, p, s are *table aliases* which you should always use as good practice for referring to tables, see how using m.movie_id is much shorter and saves repeating the full table name.

Comment: Change Stu's answer to `join stars s on s.movie_id = m.id`. Problem solved. This is the best solution.